# How to access Finder's "Date Added" field from Terminal without MDLS

Tags: finder, bash, apfs

[MacOS Ventura]

I need to move some files off a drive that is nearing its capacity to another drive while preserving the original `Date Added` in its new location.  Since I've noticed that MacOS sometimes resets the `Date Added` attribute when I use `Finder` to move files around, including when a file is moved to another drive, I am planning to write a `bash` script that will move the files for me and then set the date attributes when the move finishes.

In preparation for writing my script, I have been examining the results of several ways of retrieving the date attributes of my files.  I've tried `stat`, `gstat`, and `GetFileInto` so far but none of them give me what I want, reliably (i.e. the result matches what `Finder` shows in its window). Since I have excluded my source drive from Spotlight's indexing service, I cannot use `mdls` for this.

`GetFileInfo` returns the `created` and `modified` dates, but neither of them match `Finder`'s `Date Added` date.

Using `stat -f %Sc -t "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S%p" <pathToFile>` to display the file's `st_ctime` seems to return a date/time that is very close to `Finder`'s `Date Added` date but it frequently differs by minutes or even hours (which are not related to time-zone adjustments). See image Finder/Console screenshots below and note the time difference :

[image]
[image]

Using `gstat -c%z <pathToFile>` to display the file's last status change, `gstat`'s equivalent of the above `stat` command, produces the same problem.

Would anyone be able to suggest other ways of doing this, including the use of other languages; e.g. python or C/C++, or tools; e.g. `debugfs`, that will always return the same date/time as `Finder` shows?

Comment: Date added isn't a file attribute, it's a Spotlight attribute. See - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/463423/preserving-date-added-when-copying-folders

Comment: But it's showing that field for a drive that isn't being indexed by Spotlight.  Thus, it must be available some other way.  This timestamp is not related to the parent folder because each fine in the folder has its own correct `Date Added`.  And, it doesn't explain why the `st_ctime` is out by hours.

Comment: Search on here for '[date added](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=date+added)' you'll find many people have had many struggles trying to figure it out.